# buy now button-php-add to cart program

Tags: php

i am doing an add to cart.everything is going good.but when i am trying to store the data from the session 2d array into the database it is not happening properly i.e. the last product's id and qty is getting stored only.

this is the page which is used to store the data in database

```
<?php
session_start();
echo "<pre>";
$value=$_SESSION['cart'];
foreach ($_SESSION['cart'] as $item) {
   // echo 'p_id: ', $item['id'], '<br />';
   // echo 'p_size: ', $item['p_size'], '<br />';
    //echo 'p_qty: ', $item['qty'], '<br /><br />';
}
//print_r($value);
echo"done";
echo $address=$_GET['add']; 
 echo "<br>";
 echo $con=$_GET['cont']; 
 echo "<br>";
 echo $mail=$_GET['mail'];
 echo "<br>";
 echo $pay=$_GET['mode'];
 echo "<br>";
 echo $total=$_GET['total'];
 echo "<br>";

 //echo "".$_SESSION['cart'];
 //echo $total=$_SESSION['id'];
 //echo $total=$_GET['total'];
 $servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "root";
$dbname = "admin1";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 
echo "connected successfully";
echo"<br>";

foreach ($_SESSION['cart'] as $value){
   // print_r($_SESSION);
//print_r($_SESSION['cart']);
    $sql="INSERT INTO orders(total,id,qty,address,cont,mail,mode) values ('".$total."','".$value['id']."','".$value['qty']."','".$address."','".$con."','".$mail."','".$pay."')";

 }
if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}
?>
```

Comment: Please, provide the Database structure, and item structure.

Comment: @abhi, have you stored values in session ? I mean try `print_r($_SESSION)` and check what you get

Comment: "***when i am trying to store the data from the session 2d array into the database it is not happening properly***" what error do you get ? When you ask a question about an error, ***ALWAYS***, post the error log. To enable error reporting to your php code append `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', '1');` at the top of your script, what does it return ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should add $conn->query($sql) in foreach loop.
Try it:

```
    <?php
    session_start();
    echo "<pre>";
    $value=$_SESSION['cart'];
    foreach ($_SESSION['cart'] as $item) {
       // echo 'p_id: ', $item['id'], '<br />';
       // echo 'p_size: ', $item['p_size'], '<br />';
        //echo 'p_qty: ', $item['qty'], '<br /><br />';
    }
    //print_r($value);
    echo"done";
    echo $address=$_GET['add']; 
     echo "<br>";
     echo $con=$_GET['cont']; 
     echo "<br>";
     echo $mail=$_GET['mail'];
     echo "<br>";
     echo $pay=$_GET['mode'];
     echo "<br>";
     echo $total=$_GET['total'];
     echo "<br>";

     //echo "".$_SESSION['cart'];
     //echo $total=$_SESSION['id'];
     //echo $total=$_GET['total'];
     $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "root";
    $password = "root";
    $dbname = "admin1";

    // Create connection
    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
    // Check connection
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    } 
    echo "connected successfully";
    echo"<br>";
    $success= false;
    foreach ($_SESSION['cart'] as $value){
       // print_r($_SESSION);
    //print_r($_SESSION['cart']);
        $sql="INSERT INTO orders(total,id,qty,address,cont,mail,mode) values ('".$total."','".$value['id']."','".$value['qty']."','".$address."','".$con."','".$mail."','".$pay."')";

         if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
             $success = true;
         } else {
             echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
             $success = false;
             break;
         }

     }

    if($success) 
    echo "New record created successfully";

?>
```

Comment: i will do...thanx once again @ Rohit Goyani